# Python 2.7: Answer Linux Dialogues With OS Module

Tags: python, linux, module, operating-system

I'm working on an emergency computer password retriever for my Mac, where it will  semi brute-force crack a password on the same computer. To do this, I need to use the login command in terminal for every combinations. To enter the commands I'm using the OS module, specifically the os.system()
method. However, the login requires input dialogue, and I'm not sure how to
input that using python. It would look like this:

> login *User*
>
> Password: *Automated input answers here*

If there isn't a way to do this, is there a way to include all parameters (User and Password)on a single line?

Comment: You might look into the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module or [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Is there specific documentation for what I was asking? I'm not very experienced with Linux, so I don't understand many of the terms. If you could just point me in the right direction?